# CCD versus CMOS Camera for Light Sensitivity

Tags: camera, light-sensor

I've been working on a light transmission technique but have not effectively been able to gather the precise data I need with the current SONY 4K handycam. I need to be able to take 5 images across the span of two hours at the same zoom and focus (can't have autofocus kick in). Many publishments have previously used a CCD camera for the light sensitivity, however, when I look up the difference between CMOS cameras and CCD cameras it seems as though CMOS should be able to detect light sensitivity at high precision. Is there a difference between CMOS and CCD when it comes to detecting light and converting them to the pixel? When should CCD be used over CMOS if there is a case?